# Auto Complete to member of other class

Tags: c#, resharper

Is it possible to just enter first letters of a static member of a class and then (by a magic shortcut) the completion list lists all possible *class.member* entries?

---

More detailed explanation:

I have 15 classes in form of:

```
class AClass
{
  public static readonly string Volumeclass = "abcd";
  //... other members
}

class AnotherClass
{
  public static readonly string Volumeclass = "xyz";
  //... other members
}
```

When I want to access these members I want type *Volumeclass* and want to get the list:

- AClass.Volumeclass
- AnotherClass.Volumeclass

by intelligence. So I need to select only the right symbol instead of remember the right class name.

I tried Smart Completion, but it did not work in that manner.

Comment: I don't believe so. Without knowing more about your project or why you need to structure it like so, it's hard to know whether another approach may be more viable - eg an Enum or Constants-only reference class.

Comment: These classes are nested? If yes you can try it with reflection.

Comment: I can't say I'm aware of such feature (ReSharper *has* this knowledge when using Go To Member). Perhaps you could [suggest it to ReSharper](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP) as a new type of completion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say that I know of such shortcut. Obviously if you use the Go To Symbol navigation (`IntelliJ:` Ctrl-Shift-Alt-T  or `Visual Studio:` Ctrl-Shift-Alt-T) , you can have a list of all `VolumeClass` properties in your code:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/YP7nd.png]

But this is not what you want. The closest I could suggest is using the `Import Symbol` completion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>) and then type the first letters of the type. It will show all globally available types, and will import the appropriate `using` directive when needed.

**Edit** Another idea is to generate this with ReSharper Live Template that would allow you to generate the statement based on the first few letters:

1. Go to ReSharper - Templates Explorer (in ReSharper 6)
2. Under **Live Templates** tab, click the **New Template** button
3. Give a name for your shortcut, for example, `vc`. Optionally, write a description.
4. In the main text area, type: `$prefix$.Volumeclass`
5. Save and exit the Templates Explorer

You can now type in your code `vc`, and then the name of the class that has the property.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok. You mean *Go To Symbol* navigation as shown in your screenshot, right? This is at least a good workaround because I get the list of all possible classes. Then I would press *ESC* and then type in the remembered class name.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the classes into a common namespace. Then after you type the dot following the namespace name, the list of classes should pop up.  After you select a class, you will still need to add the `Volumeclass` property, though.

I wouldn't restructure your namespace hierarchy just for this purpose, but it may be a good option if the classes should logically be grouped together.  If the namespace name is long, you can optionally add a *[using alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)* (e.g., `using Prods = MyCompany.MyProject.Products;`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to type the class name first

```
AClass.<now the list of static members appears>
```

Note that there are tens of thousands classes in the .NET Framework class library. Do you want millions of members appear automatically?